# strange behavior i am getting from sqlite. Same values in column but SELECT DISTINCT sees different values

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, distinct

I am getting very strange behavior from SQLite.

```
INSERT into tbltest (category,question) VALUES ('aa','t1'),('aa','t2'),('Ding 1','d1'),('Ding 1','d2');

SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM tbltest;
```

I get this data returned:

| category |
| --- |
| aa |
| aa |
| Ding 1 |

I don't understand it. I should get only `aa` and `Ding 1` in my category. Where does the extra `aa` come from? This happens as I copy the string from another program.  Somehow if it

but unfortunately when i copy it from here and paste it back it behaves correctly
so i created a link to the sqlite db. please run "select distinct category from tbltest" on it

[sql lite db link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tYXeAQthfIDA6Ec7RY0FZbhZQGPWt4U2?usp=drive_link)

Comment: A leading or trailing space? Or slightly different Unicde characters? Please paste the *real* values directly into your post *without pasting anywhere else in between*.

Comment: I only get 'aa' and 'Ding 1' with your INSERT. Run `SELECT DISTINCT 'X' || category || 'X' from tbltest;` to see whether there are white spaces.

Comment: INSERT into tbltest (category,question) VALUES ('aa','t1'),('aa','t2'),('Ding 1','d1'),('Ding 1','d2');

try this

Comment: but unfortunately when i copy it from here and paste it back it behaves correctly

Comment: there is something weird about the unicode?

Comment: Set up a dbfiddle with data that demonstrates it?

Comment: Try to run `SELECT category, unicode(substr(category, 1, 1)) as c1, unicode(substr(category, 2, 1)) as c2, len(category) as L FROM tbltest`, maybe this reveals something.

Comment: i got this, what does this mean?
category c1 c2 L 
aa 65279 97 aa
aa 97 97 aa
Ding 1 68 105 Ding 1
Ding 1 68 105 Ding 1

Comment: it is interesting, once i copied my code to the dbfiddle, i notice a red dot leading the aa.  I went to the unicode inspector and it says "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE" with the unicode 65279 which is what is shown by the code from olivier.  So it seems that there is something attaching zero width no break space from somewhere.  I suspect it may be from msexcel when i am uploading the csv. does anybody has any idea how to remove it from sqlite using query?

Comment: You could use the [SQLite Trim](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-trim/) function: `TRIM(category , X'FEFF')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably Byte order mark (UNICODE 65279), as you correctly noticed in the comment section.
To get rid of this in sqlite database you need to make use of `trim` and `replace` functions.

If you want to get rid on the import phaze, your code should look like:

```
INSERT into tbltest (category,question) VALUES 
(TRIM(REPLACE('put_your_category_value_here', '\uFEFF', '')),'t1'), 
(TRIM(REPLACE('put_your_category_value_here', '\uFEFF', '')),'t2'),
(TRIM(REPLACE('put_your_category_value_here', '\uFEFF', '')),'d1'),
(TRIM(REPLACE('put_your_category_value_here', '\uFEFF', '')),'d2')
```

Or, if you just want a correct projection, you could use that `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(REPLACE(category, '\uFEFF', ''))
FROM tbltest;
```

A little bit of explanation:

`'\uFEFF'` stands for BOM aka. "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE"